# proving this region of overlapping circles is not empty with elementary set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, euclidean-geometry

Consider a set of $N$ points $P=\{p_1, p_2, \dots p_N \}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the distance $D$ between any two pair of points is less than or equal to 2:

$$D(p_i, p_j) \le 2 
\qquad 
\forall \, i,j \in {1,\dots,N}.
$$

That is, the points $p_i$ have unit circles around each point, and each unit circle $A_i$ overlaps with the others:
[image: first picture]

> #### Question
>
> Can it be proven that the region $R$ is not empty, where $R$ is the region of all points $a$ that also have a distance $D \leq 1$ to all points in $P$? E.g.,
> $$
> R = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^2 : D(a, p_i) \leq 1 
> \qquad 
> \forall \, i\in \{1,\dots,N\} \}
> $$
>
> [image: region R]

#### Method so far:

My approach so far has been to define the set of points $A_i$ as the set of points with distance $D\leq1$ to point $p_i$. Then the condition of pairwise distances can be written as the intersection of two sets:
$$
A_i \cap A_j \ne \phi
\qquad 
\forall \, i,j \in {1,\dots,N},
$$
where $\phi$ is the empty set. The region $R$ is then the intersection of all sets $A_i$:
$$ A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_N 
= \bigcap^N_{i=1} A_i = R \neq \phi 
$$

I would proceed with a proof by induction on $N=1$ and showing $N \to N+1$ but introductory math was a long time ago so I am having trouble finishing the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just take a circle with radius 1/2

Comment: sorry, I am not following your suggestion.

Comment: Based on the definition of R, P ⊆ R, so as long as P is nonempty, you are guranteed to find a nonempty R. In order to avoid this triviality, you probably want to add that you want an R that is disjoint from P. I'd try this, consider the midpoint between two points, can you show that the midpoint is also <= 1 unit away from every point? If P is finite and |P| > 1, it cannot contain all of it's midpoints so you are guranteed a disjoint nonempty R. When |P| = 1, the problem is trivial.

Comment: If all you want is $R \neq \varnothing$, then just note that $p_1 \in A_i$ for all $i$, hence $p_1 \in R$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you for the reply. Why would $p_1 \in A_i$ for all $i$ be true? That isn't immediately obvious to me. Also, when you write $p_1$, do you mean an element of $P$, the set of points?

Comment: By definition you have that D($p_1$,$p_i$,) ≤ 1 for all i.

Comment: @SammyBlack, oh no. I have written the constraint on D wrong. It should have been $D(p_i, p_j )$ is less than 2 (i.e. the diameter of a circle with radius 1 created by the $A_i$).  This excludes the trivial case of $p_i$ being in $R$ but I don't think $R$ is empty.  Should I edit the question to reflect my intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where the $p_i$ are the three vertices of an equilateral triangle of sidelength $2$. The disks of radius $1$ about each vertex intersect with each other in just the three midpoints of each side, and obviously the overall intersection is empty. You can put any number of additional $p_i$ inside the triangle near each of the vertices without their disks reaching the center of the triangle where any mutual intersection would occur. $R$ can easily be empty.